# Trying to combine two reports is SSRS. Having trouble with subreports and adding existing shared datasets from one report to another

Tags: reporting-services, subreport, ssrs-tablix

Basically, I have two separate projects that I would like to combine into one. They each have one shared dataset. When trying to simply add the existing reports and existing shared datasets (via right click > Add > Add Existing Item) from one of the projects to another, I couldn't get things working properly. After coping a tablix from one report (the one from the other project added via right click "Add Existing Item") I get an error saying the tablix refers to an invalid dataset name. The dataset it's linked to is the one from the other project that I added via right click add existing item.

When trying to include the added report as a subreport, I got a "subreport data retrieval error" telling me to check the log file for more details. I am neither sure why I received this error nor where the log file can be found.

Am I missing something with adding/linking to datasets? Is what I'm attempting supposed to be possible?

Thanks for the help, let me know if you need more info or screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have a shared dataset you need to have a dataset in the report itself that points to it. It sounds like that these links have gotten messed up as you moved the files around to different projects. I'd suggest deleting the datasets that are currently in the reports and making new ones to link to the shared dataset. Even if they look okay when you look at the properties it may be that some GUID for an object has changed (total guess) and things just need to be updated to make sure they work properly again. Then fix up any elements on the reports that get broken by doing this. Hopefully then everything will work correctly.